# Custom LoadBalaner probing for https endpoints in Azure CloudServices

Tags: node.js, https, load-balancing, azure-cloud-services

**About my case:** I have a node.js REST API deployed in Azure CloudService. The node.js process is hosted in IIS using iisnode. Because of this the default probing doesn't work well as it might be that the entire IIS process is down or something when wrong in the node.exe process and the default probing will not encounter the issue. As a solution I am trying to implement custom probing.

**The Problem:** I am trying to make the Azure LoadBalancer use a custom probe endpoint for one of my CloudServices as discussed in [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/) article. I am struggling with the fact that it seems custom LoadBalancing probes are available only for public input endpoints using http, tcp or udp.

In my case I have the limitation that I should expose only endpoints under the https protocol. Here is my CloudService definition:

```xml
<ServiceDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="dec-api-server" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="dec-api" vmsize="Small">
    <Certificates>
        <Certificate name="HttpsCertificate" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="CA" />
    </Certificates>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="HttpsCertificate"/>
      <InputEndpoint name="internalProbingEndpoint" port="8091" protocol="http" loadBalancerProbe="customProbe"/>
    </Endpoints>
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" />
          <Binding name="internalProbingBinding" endpointName="internalProbingEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
  </WebRole>
  <LoadBalancerProbes>
    <LoadBalancerProbe name="customProbe" intervalInSeconds="30" path="/probe" timeoutInSeconds="60" port="8091" protocol="http"/>
  </LoadBalancerProbes>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I have tried the following things:

1. I defined the loadBalancerProbe="customProbe" attribute in the httpsIn endpoint and modified protocol and the port in the LoadBalancerProbe element but it seems it is not possible as the deployment fails with a complain that it is not valid XML.protocol=https is not supported there.
2. Then I thought I can add second input endpoint using http that will be used for probing and will disable the network traffic for other networks using Endpoint ACL and allow only the LoadBalancer to access it. It works, or at least I can see in the IIS log that the LoadBalancer calls the /probe endpoint but in case it returns status 500 it takes out of rotation only this Endpoint but not the entire WebRole or Instance of the CloudService. The calls through the HttpsIn endpoint still hit the machine where the probe endpoint returns 500.

**The Question:** Is there a way to configure the Azure LoadBalancer for a CloudService to use a custom endpoint for probing when HTTPS is used?

Is there a workaround if that is not supported?

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Kaloyan, did you solve this problem? I have very similar issue. I'm running Azure Cloud Service which has HTTP and HTTPS endpoints, LB probe is HTTP but HTTPS traffic is not offloaded when probe returns 500, it still goes to the unhealthy instance.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did resolve it. In my case I have a have only HTTPS enabled and I do not allow not encrypted traffic. I enabled the the sample above the HTTP endpoint only because of the load balancer but the mistake I did was that I added the attribute loadBalancerProbe="customProbe" in the HTTP endpoint while it should be in the HTTPS endpoint. So the schema is that you instruct the custom NLB probing for the https endpoint to use the http endpoint. I didn't need to have the http enabled publicly so I disabled it with ACL list, which doesn't block the NLB fortunately.

Comment: If you need more details I can give you an example configuration tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Kaloyan, I'm also trying to get probe to work with by https request, but when I add the loadBalancerProbe setting on https endpoint, my site no longer works, all requests are rejected and the probe is not even calling its path. Could you share you example configuration - thanks

Comment: Found the issue, I had not included the port attribute in the LoadBalancerProbe , and it then defaults to the same port as the endpoint - this is ok for http, as they all use port 80. But when configuring it for endpoint htttps, the probe still has to work on http, so it needed to have port="80" specified. Once I added that, it all worked as expected